# Putting method in "return", in Java, is the correct approach?

Tags: java

In classes I would inherit these methods protected override, in order to change the behavior of the methods that it uses. Are shown below practice, correct? If not, why?

Simple type and immutable objects:

```
class A{
    (...)
    public int aA(){
        int b=1;
        return this.bB(b); // It is about this place.
    }

    protected int bB(int b){
        b=2*b;
        return b;
    }
    (...)    
}

class B extends A{
    (...)
    @Override
    protected int bB(int b){
        return b-1;
    }
}
```

In class A, I want to use a method bB() in method aA(), two methods are implemented in this class. The method bB () I put the "return" method aA(). Then B defines a class that inherits from A, and overrides the method bB(). As a result, the method aA() in class B works differently than the method aA() in Class A.

What if putting methods in return, which returns objects with the ability to modify?
As it is with putting static methods in return?
Whether this has any implications for concurrent programming?

Comment: You only return integers in your examples.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

Comment: Find out how to return a lambda expression.

Comment: I know that in class A method aA () in return, referring to the reference method returns an int, the result is an int, but that this piece of code refers to a piece of code outside the method, I ask whether such practice is correct?

Comment: He does not want to class A was abstract, it should be possible to create the objects. The point is that the method aA () by default is fully functional, that is, implementation bB () is full, but it can be override, in classes that inherit after it, which results in a change of action methods aA (). It is also about putting this method in return. I do not mean returning method of a type as implementation of the "functional interface".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be asking about whether the above code is the correct way to write a method that overrides a method in its superclass.

Yes it is the correct way to do it.

Yes, that is a good way to "change behavior" ... though you are only changing the behavior for the new class (`B`)

> What if returned objects with the ability to modify?

Same answer.

> As it is with returning of static and nonstatic methods?

No.  Static methods are non-polymorphic.  You cannot override static methods.

In your example, if `bB` was static then the `@Overrides` annotation would give you a compilation error.  If you removed it, you would find that the call to `bB()` in `aA` would always call `A.bB` and never `B.bB`.

Note that calling a static method with the syntax `this.someStaticMethod(...)` is legal, but bad style.  It looks like the call will be polymorphic but in fact it isn't.

> Whether this has any implications for concurrent programming?

No particular implications.

---

On the other hand, if you are actually asking about methods that return other methods ... your example code doesn't do that.

Comment: I do not mean overriding the static method and the insertion of a static method in return.

Comment: The title was not precise, it has been changed. I thought that in the post explained well what I mean, but apparently not to the end.

Comment: The problem is that *"putting method in return"* and *"putting this method in return"* are both bad English, and I'm having difficulty understand what you really mean.  And your example code is not helping because it DOES NOT return a method ... if that is what you are actually asking about.

Comment: If it is wrong, and you already know what's going on, how to write proper English? I mean placing method to another method, the implementation of the two methods is in a different place, and most importantly, this method of placing concrete in return. As you can see I am not yet proficient in English.

Comment: I can't tell you the right way to write what you are trying to say ... unless I can >>understand<< what you are saying. And I'm still not sure I understand what you are saying.  But does my Answer answer your questions?

Comment: Yes. Only the content of static methods, and the "return of the method" at the end, it's not what I meant.

Comment: In class A, I want to use a method bB() in method aA(), two methods are implemented in this class. The method bB () I put the "return" method aA(). Then B defines a class that inherits from A, and overrides the method bB(). This makes the method aA() in class B works differently than the method aA() class A. Is Now this is understandable? I question whether this practice is correct?

Comment: Please help as to title, because I fall asleep negatives.